# Dynamic routes in Next.JS Route groups

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

In my Next.JS app, I have the following [id].tsx:

```
"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;

  return <p>Post: {id}</p>;
};

export default Post;
```

(1) It works FINE if it is placed in the folder "test", so its location is
`test/[id].tsx`

(2) It does NOT work if I place it in a "route group", so if its location is
`(mygroup)/test/[id].tsx` -> It gives me an 404 error.

I accept any answer that explains to me briefly who I can make it work with the route group.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. My problem was, that my Next.JS project is setup with:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

So my folder structure should look like this:

`(mygroup)/test/[id]/page.tsx`

And page.tsx should look like:

```
"use client";

const Post = ({ params }) => {
  const { id } = params;

  return <p>Post: {id}</p>;
};

export default Post;
```